# Could not found method compile() in gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, build.gradle, android-cardview

I'm new to Android Studio and android development and developing my first application.

I want to use `CarView` and `RecyclerView` to display data. According to many tutorials on it, I need to add following dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

This is how my `build.gradle` is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

But on Sync gradle, it gives error as

```
Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

I tried many solutions from Google search but couldn't found any working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio creates a project with two build.gradle files.

This section of code

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Goes into `app/build.gradle` of the project. You also want to update the 21 version number to the SDK that you're compiling with.

After that, you also have to `install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.`

Answer (score 0):

As it says on the error, you have to download and install the Android Support Repository from the sdk manager.

To do that, go to the Android Studio toolbar, click on Tools > Android > SDK Manager.
Click on the SDK Tools tab, and search for Support Repository and check Android Support Repository and Google Repository.

Click on Apply Button, and wait for the repositories to download and install. When it finishes, close SDK Manager and try to sync Gradle again.

And also, as @cricket_007 says, move your dependencies to the `build.gradle (Module: ..)` file. 

You can also add dependencies by going to File > Project Structure (or pressing `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S`), the option below modules (probably named app), to the tab `Dependencies` and pressing the green `+` button.